# How to get all the customer email using graphQl in magento2

Tags: magento2, customer, email, magento2.4.5, graphql

I need all the customer email using graphQl in magento2. Who ever registered in magento those customers email addresses. I need to get from Api.
Please help for this

Comment: There is no such tipe of GraphQL API, as it is storefront api and works in scope of one user

Comment: ok thank you for the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please add the following files to your existing module.**

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc**

**schema.graphqls**

```
type Query {
    getAllCustomer: [allEmail] @resolver(class:"VendorName\\ModuleName\\Model\\Resolver\\AllEmails") @doc(description:"It returns information all customer Email query ") @cache(cacheable: false)
}
type allEmail @doc(description: "It returns information all customer Email query") {
    email: String
}
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Model/Resolver**

**AllEmails.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;

class AllEmails implements ResolverInterface
{
    protected $_customerFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
    ) {
        $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    }

    public function resolve(
        Field $field,
        $context,
        ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null
    ) {
        return $this->_customerFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect("*")->load();
    }
}
```

> **Please run the following Magento commands.**

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento s:s:d -f
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento s:d:c
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento cache:clean
```

> **Then run the query below to retrieve all customer emails.**

```
query getAllCustomer {
  getAllCustomer {
    email
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]